# Maven to build Oracle ADF projects, jws, jpr, using Ojmake and Ojdeploy plugins

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, build, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

There is a lot to answer, but if you know please give it a try

Standard ADF Fusion Middleware Application would have following structure:

```
Application (Described as aggregating pom)
├── Model (jar project)
└── ViewController (war project)
```

I am having problems with Maven and ojmake, ojdeploy plugins. I am moving a lot of Oracle ADF applications to maven builds from scripts/ant. I end up with packaged files being twice as much in size, this is because of dependencies. Worse is then I satisfy Maven dependencies and build fails on ojmake/okdeploy stage, this is what I don't understand completely: The library (Or Class) has been resolved and .java file gets compiled using standard maven compile plugin but inside ojdeploy for example I would get package not found error that was resolved earlier.

```
[INFO] [16:37:14] Successful compilation: 0 errors, 0 warnings.
[INFO] Total time: (34604 msec) 34 seconds 604 msec
......
[INFO] --- ojdeploy:12.1.2-0-0:deploy (default) @ ViewController ---
[INFO] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\jdeveloper\jdev\bin\ojdeploy.exe -J-DUseMaven=true -workspace C:\git\SXDOCS_SHEDULER\ViewController/../SXDOCS_SHEDULER.jws -project ViewController -profile application_production
......
[INFO] Error(19,30): package org.apache.http.client does not exist
[INFO] Error(188,97): cannot find symbol;  symbol:   class ClientProtocolException;  location: class sch.ShedulerPackage.SchedulerWorker
```

And this dependency has that class:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Can someone please lay out how to properly put together Oracle ADF application and maven build? Oracle docs are quite useless and there isn't much information on the web on Java EE and especially Maven in Fusion Middleware applications.

Some more thoughts and questions:

1. Running mvn package goal would make both ojmake and ojdeploy to execute
2. This leads to creation of model.jar, vc.war, and application.pom in Maven
3. This also assembles (Just now looks like magic) the web app module and .ear file though there is not a pom file with packaging ear.
4. Are jar and war files generated by Maven just rubbish?
5. Is there any point in compiling code by Maven? Can I skip that? Code is compiled twice, using maven-compile and ojmake?
6. To run Maven on VC I require compiled Model project as an artifact, does it mean I have to install Model.jar to repo? Maven would not run without it, but Ojdeploy knows where are the classes, complete mess...
7. Ojdeploy deploys to a .ear file. Can I deploy to a remote server?
8. What is the role of .jws and .jpr files? What is the role of their own classpathes and libraries? How do deployment profiles come into play when maven is executed?
9. What are the actual libraries required for an empty VC, Model and Application poms and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give a shot here by answering some of your questions.

1. According to maven lifecycle ([maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)) running the maven package goal goes through validate, compile, test and package phases. So if you have a ojdeploy/ojmake plugin in your pom that runs at package phase it would execute.
2. Ok.
3. I guess the ojdeploy takes care of that.
4. No, as per answer 1, they are validated, compiled, tested and packaged.
5. As you run the package goal maven takes care of compilation etc. Perhaps you can skip ojmake plugin.
6. Running the maven install goal would install your Model.jar into the repo, but you can do this manually ofcourse before running any maven goal on the VC.
7. You can deploy the generated ear to a remote server (i.e. weblogic).
8. The .jws file is JDeveloper specific for your application; the .jpr files are JDeveloper specific for your Model and VC projects. My best guess is that's where JDeveloper holds its classpath entries and other project specifics so that ojmake and ojdeploy can do their respective jobs.
9. This is very project specific. Perhaps a good tip is to let JDeveloper create a pom for your application (File -> New -> Application pom) and projects so you can see what JDeveloper thinks you need for dependencies.

Comment: As a JDev project is converted to a Maven project JDev 12 stops using jws-file for classpath. The jws-file is still needed for other stuff, but not for classpath entries. Project dependencies are managed by pom.xml. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78006255